# How to create a running balance from multiple price and payment amounts for the same order?

Tags: r

I have the following input dataset with the following columns:

1. `OrderID`: Unique ID for each order placed
2. `ItemID`: Unique ID for each item within each order
3. `Amount`: Corresponding price for each item
4. `ActualPayment`: Actual payment made for each *order*. There could be multiple payments for a single order regardless of the number of items purchased, so `Price` and `ActualPayment` is a many-to-many relationship. A single `ActualPayment` could underpay, overpay, or exactly pay the `Amount` requested. Excess `ActualPayment` will be carried over, whereas partial payment will rely on the next payment to make full.

**Input data:**

```
  OrderID ItemID Amount ActualPayment
1       1      1   1000           500
2       1      2   1000           600
3       1     NA     NA           800
4       2      1   2000          1000
5       2      2   2000          1000
6       2     NA     NA          1000
7       2     NA     NA          1000
8       3      1    500           600
9       3      2    300           200
```

Based on the input data, I would like to create a running `Balance` for each *item*, given that `ActualPayment` from the previous item could carry over to the next item when there is an excess.

1. `ActualPaymentID`: Unique per `ActualPayment` within each order
2. `Payable`: `Amount` yet to be paid
3. `Payment`: Exact amount paid for each item. For example, on row 2-3, `ActualPayment == 600` is split across `ItemID` 1-2 because 500 out of 600 covers the remaining `Payable` exactly.
4. `Balance`: The first row for each `ItemID` is always the remainder amount (i.e. `Amount - Payment`). The following entries should be `-Payment`

**Output data:**

```
   OrderID ItemID Amount ActualPayment ActualPaymentID Payable Payment Balance
1        1      1   1000           500               1    1000     500     500
2        1      1   1000           600               2     500     500    -500
3        1      2   1000           600               2    1000     100     900
4        1      2   1000           800               3     900     800    -800
5        2      1   2000          1000               1    2000    1000    1000
6        2      1   2000          1000               2    1000    1000   -1000
7        2      2   2000          1000               3    2000    1000    1000
8        2      2   2000          1000               4    1000    1000   -1000
9        3      1    500           600               1     500     500       0
10       3      2    300           600               1     300     100     200
11       3      2    300           200               2     200     200    -200
```

**Problem:**

I'm mainly stuck on how to create the `Payment` column and insert a row when `ActualPayment` is needed to be split into two. I would also need to spread `ItemID` and `Amount` across `Payment`s made based on which item the payments are for.

**Data:**

```
input <- data.frame(OrderID = c(rep(1, 3), rep(2, 4), rep(3, 2)),
                    ItemID = c(1, 2, NA, 1, 2, NA, NA, 1, 2),
                    Amount = c(1000, 1000, NA, 2000, 2000, NA, NA, 500, 300),
                    ActualPayment = c(500, 600, 800, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 600, 200))

output <- data.frame(OrderID = c(rep(1, 4), rep(2, 4), rep(3, 3)),
                     ItemID = c(rep(1, 2), rep(2, 2), rep(1, 2), rep(2, 2), 1, 2, 2),
                     Amount = c(1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 500, 300, 300),
                     ActualPayment = c(500, 600, 600, 800, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 600, 600, 200),
                     ActualPaymentID = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2),
                     Payable = c(1000, 500, 1000, 900, 2000, 1000, 2000, 1000, 500, 300, 200),
                     Payment = c(500, 500, 100, 800, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 500, 100, 200),
                     Balance = c(500, -500, 900, -800, 1000, -1000, 1000, -1000, 0, 200, -200))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let’s first disentangle the items and payments into separate data frames.
This will make them easier to work with:

```r
library(tidyverse)

items <- input %>% 
  filter(!is.na(ItemID)) %>% 
  distinct(OrderID, ItemID, Amount)

items
#>   OrderID ItemID Amount
#> 1       1      1   1000
#> 2       1      2   1000
#> 3       2      1   2000
#> 4       2      2   2000
#> 5       3      1    500
#> 6       3      2    300

payments <- input %>% 
  group_by(OrderID) %>% 
  mutate(ActualPaymentID = row_number()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(OrderID, ActualPaymentID, ActualPayment)  

payments
#> # A tibble: 9 x 3
#>   OrderID ActualPaymentID ActualPayment
#>     <dbl>           <int>         <dbl>
#> 1       1               1           500
#> 2       1               2           600
#> 3       1               3           800
#> 4       2               1          1000
#> 5       2               2          1000
#> 6       2               3          1000
#> 7       2               4          1000
#> 8       3               1           600
#> 9       3               2           200
```

It also helps to focus on just one order to build up a solution that we can then apply to all of the orders:

```r
order1_payments <- payments %>% filter(OrderID == 1) %>% select(-OrderID)
order1_items <- items %>% filter(OrderID == 1) %>% select(-OrderID)
```

To get a running balance, we’ll want to add up payment amounts until the full cost of an item is filled, or vice versa. This means we’ll want to find the amounts at which either the payment changes or the item changes. Each combination of payment and item will then form a new row in the result. We can do this by getting the unique cumulative sums of both vectors:

```r
p <- order1_payments$ActualPayment
i <- order1_items$Amount

( p_csum <- cumsum(p) )
#> [1]  500 1100 1900
( i_csum <- cumsum(i) )
#> [1] 1000 2000
( r_csum <- sort(unique(c(p_csum, i_csum))) )
#> [1]  500 1000 1100 1900 2000
```

We can then use `match()` to find out where items and payments end, and then get the number of rows each item and payment spans:

```r
( p_rows <- diff(c(0, match(p_csum, r_csum))) )
#> [1] 1 2 1
( i_rows <- diff(c(0, match(i_csum, r_csum))) )
#> [1] 2 3
```

With this, we can create vectors that can be used to index the data to create the combinations we want, making sure they have equal length.

```r
na_pad <- function(x, length) {
  replace(rep(NA, length), seq_along(x), x)
}

n_rows <- length(r_csum)
( row_p <- na_pad(rep(seq_along(p), p_rows), n_rows) )
#> [1]  1  2  2  3 NA
( row_i <- na_pad(rep(seq_along(i), i_rows), n_rows) )
#> [1] 1 1 2 2 2
```

The amount payable on each row can be determined by subtracting each row’s payment from the cumulative item totals:

```r
( payable <- i_csum[row_i] - lag(r_csum, default = 0) )
#> [1] 1000  500 1000  900  100
```

All that remains is to build the resulting data frame:

```r
combs <- cbind(
  order1_items[row_i, ],
  order1_payments[row_p, ],
  Payable = payable,
  Payment = diff(c(0, r_csum))
)

combs
#>     ItemID Amount ActualPaymentID ActualPayment Payable Payment
#> 1        1   1000               1           500    1000     500
#> 1.1      1   1000               2           600     500     500
#> 2        2   1000               2           600    1000     100
#> 2.1      2   1000               3           800     900     800
#> 2.2      2   1000              NA            NA     100     100
```

To apply the result to each order, let’s put the process in a function:

```r
resolve_payments <- function(payments, items) {
  p <- payments$ActualPayment
  i <- items$Amount

  p_csum <- cumsum(p)
  i_csum <- cumsum(i)
  r_csum <- sort(unique(c(p_csum, i_csum)))

  ( p_rows <- diff(c(0, match(p_csum, r_csum))) )
  ( i_rows <- diff(c(0, match(i_csum, r_csum))) )

  na_pad <- function(x, length) {
    replace(rep(NA, length), seq_along(x), x)
  }

  n_rows <- length(r_csum)
  ( row_p <- na_pad(rep(seq_along(p), p_rows), n_rows) )
  ( row_i <- na_pad(rep(seq_along(i), i_rows), n_rows) )
  ( payable <- i_csum[row_i] - lag(r_csum, default = 0) )

  combs <- cbind(
    items[row_i, ],
    payments[row_p, ],
    Payable = payable,
    Payment = diff(c(0, r_csum))
  )

  combs
}
```

Now, we can create a data frame with one row for each order, and with list columns containing the items and payments included in each of them:

```r
orders <- items %>% 
  distinct(OrderID) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  nest_join(items) %>% 
  nest_join(payments)
#> Joining, by = "OrderID"
#> Joining, by = "OrderID"

orders
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   OrderID items            payments        
#> *   <dbl> <list>           <list>          
#> 1       1 <df[,2] [2 x 2]> <tibble [3 x 2]>
#> 2       2 <df[,2] [2 x 2]> <tibble [4 x 2]>
#> 3       3 <df[,2] [2 x 2]> <tibble [2 x 2]>
```

And finally, we apply the function to each order to get the final result:

```r
orders %>% 
  group_by(OrderID) %>% 
  group_modify(~ resolve_payments(.x$payments[[1]], .x$items[[1]]))
#> # A tibble: 12 x 7
#> # Groups:   OrderID [3]
#>    OrderID ItemID Amount ActualPaymentID ActualPayment Payable Payment
#>      <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>           <int>         <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1       1      1   1000               1           500    1000     500
#>  2       1      1   1000               2           600     500     500
#>  3       1      2   1000               2           600    1000     100
#>  4       1      2   1000               3           800     900     800
#>  5       1      2   1000              NA            NA     100     100
#>  6       2      1   2000               1          1000    2000    1000
#>  7       2      1   2000               2          1000    1000    1000
#>  8       2      2   2000               3          1000    2000    1000
#>  9       2      2   2000               4          1000    1000    1000
#> 10       3      1    500               1           600     500     500
#> 11       3      2    300               1           600     300     100
#> 12       3      2    300               2           200     200     200
```

The touch-ups of removing the rows that could not be paid for and calculating the `Balance` are left “as an exercise for the reader”.

<sup>Created on 2019-09-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you!